# Populating multiselect OpenDialog with a series of filenames

Tags: delphi, multi-select, fileopendialog, topendialog

I use an OpenDialog with Multiselect enabled to allow more than one jpg file to be displayed on a screen.  When the dialog is closed, I iterate through the Files list and create a delimited string of filenames which is stored in a memo field of an Access table.

If the user wants to edit the selection, I want to parse the delimited string value and put the filenames into the OpenDialog and have it displayed in the same way it was when they were first selected, however, the dialog only has one filename in the edit box of the form.  When the dialog is closed, only this file is in the files list.

How do I re-populate the Files list?  We are using Delphi XE on W7-10.

Also, is it possible to have the list "unsorted"?  The files list returns filenames in a sorted order, there is no "sorted" property.  I would like to be able to have the user select the files in the order they wish to display them.  At the moment, sorting is done in a custom editing form that allows them to be dragged to position.  This is written out to the delimited string and written to the table.

Comment: There are two questions here

Comment: Sorry, I had created the original question, which was more important, and thought that anyone who could answer the first question would probably have the knowledge to answer the second, which is less important.

Comment: Don't you simply populate `Files`?

Comment: That is what I thought too, but when you do it, you don't get what you expect!  I have now created a special editing form with a list of filenames in the order they are displayed.  You can move them to where you want and press a button to insert more files, possibly from different folders, and move these around.